# create an expensive synchronous task, to test UI responsiveness

Tags: javascript, performance

So i am trying to figure out how to render images to the browser, without crashing it or making the UI unresponsive. I'm using this code to load (a lot) of thumbnails to the screen, and the goal is to keep the spinner gif spinning in every LI, without glitches, while the images render one by one, inside each LI.

This is the approach i am testing now, but i need some help in simulating expensive operations, like in the commented for loop; this for loop is, i think, too expensive; the setTimeout works fine (emulating the job of a web worker), but i would like to test with some expensive synchronous task;

the for loop totally freezes the app; do you have any other suggestions?

```
renderThumbnail = function(imageObj){ 
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'photo-list-item loading-spinner';
    photoList.appendChild(li);
    thumbnailListItems.push(li);
    imageObj.load().then(function(){
        thumbnailRenderQueue.push(imageObj);
        if(!renderingThumbnails){
            renderQueue();
        }
    });
};

var renderQueue = function(){
    renderingThumbnails = true;
    (function renderOne(){
        var li = thumbnailListItems.shift();
        var imageObj = thumbnailRenderQueue.shift();
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 120;
        canvas.height = 80;
        // setTimeout(function(){
            // for(var i = 0; i < 9999999; i++){ 10000*10000; }
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            li.appendChild(canvas);
            li.classList.remove('loading-spinner');
            ctx.drawImage(imageObj.image, 0, 0, 120, 80);
            if(thumbnailRenderQueue.length > 0){
                renderOne();
            } else {
                renderingThumbnails = false;
            }
        // }, 1000);
    })();
```

Comment: Javascript in a browser is single threaded.  An expensive synchronous task will starve other tasks wishing to get events (such as timers, click, mouse, repaint, etc...) until that synchronous task is done.  That's just how the browser event loop works.  The only way to prevent starvation is to avoid the expensive synchronous task such that all work is broken into small pieces (often initiated via a `setTimeout()`) so that no piece runs for too long.  It is browser dependent how an animated gif behaves during a long synchronous task which is not something you control.

Comment: Use a value smaller than `9999999`?